# Secure CSS, JS and images with custom forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, authentication

I've built a custom forms authentication. I don't use any of the IIS' features for forms authentication so far.

Currently the authentication is triggered by one line of code in every codebehind file (which then modifies the response). This means only files with codebehind (like .aspx) can be secured.

Now how can i secure other types of files (like JS, CSS and images)? The best way i can imagine is to use a dynamic url, so something like "mydomain.com/files/getFile.aspx#css/examplefile.css". But i guess there's a smarter way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to be using IIS7 or newer and integrated pipeline.

Then you have to create a HttpModule and register that under `system.webServer` section in your configuration file.

This module will be invoked for every request, both ASP.NET (`.aspx` etc.) and static files.

[Walkthrough: Creating and Registering a Custom HTTP Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms227673.aspx)

Comment: Could you explain why i have to use IIS7 or newer and integrated pipeline? In the article it says IIS6 or newer and classic as well as pipline.

Comment: For IIS6 your modules will not be executed for non-managed handlers (such as a static file request).

Comment: Works fine so far. Now inside the Application_BeginRequest event, how do i get the "Page" object i usually have onpageload? And will context.SkipAuthorization = true; skip other authentications, like windows autentications in a request?

Comment: You can't get the Page object in BeginRequest because the handler (that is the Page) is not yet initialized. You only have access to HttpContext.

Comment: Thanks, worked around the page object. But currently, after following the guide, it looks like the module is only executed for .aspx files. All my other files (CSS, JS) throw an error 500 ("ModuleX could not be loaded"). I think this is because only the folder containing the .aspx file is set as an application in IIS. Also it contains the DLL in it's bin folder. The css folder for example is no application and doens't have the DLL in it's bin folder. Is there a way to make all requests use the same DLL?

Comment: You must either make the CSS folder its own application and copy the bin folder there or move the CSS folder under the application folder.